# Proof using contradiction

Tags: logic, proof-theory

I'm trying to prove there is no smallest positive irrational number. Now I now I need to assume that there is a smallest positive irrational number, say N. But now I'm stuck. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Yes. If $r$ is your proposed smallest positive irrational number, then consider $r/2$.

Comment: So i can still divide an irrational number?

Comment: A number is a number. You can do all four operations (except division by zero) on any pair of real numbers; that's kind of the point of the real number system.

Comment: Ok I was just making sure I didn't want to screw the proof up. haha thanks

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ has the algebraic structure of an [ordered field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field). In particular, you can define a [division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Abstract_algebra) on it. If you don't want to divide, suppose $r=\frac{a}{b}$ and consider $r':=\frac{a}{2b}$.